# Google Maps visible on some devices, error on others

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps

There is a problem with my google maps [here](http://www.wellnessallin.be/contact.php)

it is visible on my pc, also with other browsers and in a private session and other devices. 
Unfortunately it is not visible for my customer, the owner of the website and some other devices.
The console says

> Google Maps API warning: [NoApiKeys](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys)

and

> You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page.
>   This may cause unexpected errors.

This is what I have:

```
<div id="map" style="width:100%; height:450px;"></div>
                    <script>
                    function initMap() {
                        var myLatLng = {lat: 50.8394968, lng: 4.2694918};

                        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                            zoom: 16,
                            center: myLatLng
                        });

                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: myLatLng,
                            map: map,
                            title: 'Hello World!'
                        });
                        marker.setMap(map);

                        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                            content:"<p style='text-align:center;'>Wellness All-In <br>"+
                            "Broekstraat 56 – 1700 Dilbeek<br>"+
                            "0496/44.55.56<br>"+
                            "aline@wellnessallin.be</p>"
                        });

                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                            infowindow.open(map,marker);
                        });
                    }
                    </script>
                    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA5RLhWKFn4P2XVc8G_yho1oun7xS1RtfU&callback=initMap"></script>

                </div>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have included Google Maps twice. Once with the key

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA5RLhWKFn4P2XVc8G_yho1oun7xS1RtfU&callback=initMap"></script>
```

and once without

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

Remove the second include statement.

Your site also shows the following error :

> Google Maps API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error
>   Your site URL to be authorized:
>   http://www.wellnessallin.be/contact.php

Make sure your website is added to the list of allowed referrers in Google API console for the specified key.